# How can I start a new text on my iphone message app?

Tags: iphone

I can't seem to find a way to start a new text thread on my Iphone, does anyone know how to do that without deleting the entire contact, and then re-entering it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean just starting a new message thread...Choose the icon in the upper right corner. It has what looks like a pencil drawing on paper. If you are referring to starting a new thread with a person with whom you already have a thread, you cannot have two active threads with the same person.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a new thread by creating a group text including yourself as a recipient, but this will only work once.